# How to open a .txt file after using netstat command with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, prompt, netstat

I am trying to open a simple log.txt file (in this example comandos.txt) after running a netstat command like so:

```
@ echo off

echo. >> C:\comandos.txt
netstat -b -o 1 >> C:\comandos.txt
start C:\comandos.txt
```

After netstat Prompt Windows won't close and comandos.txt won't open.
Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: your code works here. What is your Windows version?

Comment: Windows 8, just so you know, I am running it as Administrator. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your `1` in the `netstat` command specifies the interval which would redisplay the statistics again and again, which is why you prompt window doesn't shut down. Just using `netstat -b -o` should be enough.

Comment: I took it out but still, same again, prompt window don't close and .txt don't open.

Comment: Try just `netstat -b -o` in another prompt and see how much time it takes, that would explain the window being there for a long time.

Comment: But taking out 1 was a good idea anyway, thanks

Comment: If the prompt window closes (which I expect it to after `netstat` completes) and still .txt doesn't come up, you should probably associate the .txt file extension to open with some default program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ echo off

echo. >> C:\comandos.txt
netstat -b -o >> C:\comandos.txt
start C:\comandos.txt
```

The above snippet works fine. Note that you were specifying the `interval` in `netstat` command which redisplays the statistics again and again. Also, because you have `echo` turned `off` and display redirected to the file, the empty prompt window showing up for a long time would send wrong signals. Show some message like `Collecting information...` or similar.

Also, given that the command needs to resolve addresses and depends on the number of processes  with network connection, it may take some time for `netstat` to complete which would be system dependent.

Comment: I tried doing it. Echoing  normally and no loop behind it. I tried Ctrl+C and it asked me to terminate Batch.

Comment: What I meant was, start up a command prompt (cmd.exe) and enter `netstat -b -o` and see in how much time the command completes. The command has to resolve foreign addresses and depends on the number of processes connected with the network. (my system here takes 20secs)

Comment: Wow, it really takes a long time, I will wait for a minute to see what happens.

Comment: Beatiful, worked like a charm, thanks very much! I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this resolves your complete question, maybe you could mark this as the answer. Thanks.